# Bootstrap Double DropDown and Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I uploaded the dropdown to my web site, somehow it looks double:)

Like this:

[image: Here]

But, that's not the only problem,

Another problem is that Elements do not appear in the `<select>` list, but when I add some sample `<option>Sample</option>` all elements appear.

My Select Codes:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="List" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count>1">
                                        <option>asdd</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>ssasd</option>
                                        <option>adsd</option>
                                        <option>a</option>
                                        <option>sasd</option>
                                        <option>adsd</option>
                                    </select>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "db/../..",
    dataType : "json"
  })
    .done(function( result ) {
      if ( typeof result.error !== "undefined" ) {
        // Error
        dialog.close();
        alertDialog( "Hata", result.error, BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER );
      } else if ( typeof result.List !== "undefined" && $.isArray( result.List ) ) {
        // A proper result
        if ( result.FirmList.length < 1 ) {
          // No records found
          dialog.close();
          alertDialog( "Error", "Nothing Found!", BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING );
        } else {
          // Parse details
          var f = result.List;

          for ( var i = 0; i < f.length; i++ ) {
            var op = document.createElement( "option" );
            op.value = f[ i ].Id;
            op.textContent = f[ i ].Name;

            document.getElementById( "List" ).appendChild( op );
          }

          $( "#select" ).chosen();

        }
      } else {
        dialog.close();
        alertDialog( "Error", "No Idea!", BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER );
      }
    })
    .fail(function(a, b, c) {
      dialog.close();
      alertDialog( "Error",
        "Error",
        BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER );
    });
```

Comment: If I remove the <option>s, nothing appears in the dropdown.

Comment: What's in `result.List`?

Comment: List of sample data like; Texas, New York, Los Angeles

Comment: So it isn't an array of objects?  If your data isn't arranged like (for instance) `[{Id: 1, Name: "Texas"}, {Id: 2, Name: "New York"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Los Angeles"}]` then `f[i].Id` is always going to give you `undefined`.  Seems like all your `options` tags would be empty if the data is arranged as a list of strings.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your time. But that's not the problem, The main problem is appearing the dropdown double.

Comment: Might be `$( "#select" ).chosen();`.  Your `select` tag has `id="List"` not `id="select"`.

Comment: Thank you. I added twice the JS lib. Problem solved:)